# Download item from sharepoint list

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

I have to fetch some files from a sharepoint List (www.domain.sharepoint.com/site/appname/List/ListName)

I can deserialize the link that target to each item of the list but I can't download those items through the links.

How can I download the files that are stored in the list ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you visited this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878939/get-a-list-of-files-from-sharepoint-and-download-the-latest-file

Comment: I've just tried the solution. But it uses methods that are not declare in the sharepoint.client so I can't try the exact solution. With this solution, I can get connected with the sharepoint list but I can't get the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use GetFileByServativeUrl to get file object and then download the file stream, here is a code snippet for your reference:

```
 using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx"))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web, a => a.ServerRelativeUrl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/jerrydev/Shared%20Documents/test.png");
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                if (file != null)
                {
                    FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    var folderpath = @"c:\downloadfolder";
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderpath))
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
                    }
                    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(folderpath + @"\" + file.Name, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works with this package :  Install-Package Microsoft.Sharepoint.2013.Client.16 -Version 1.0.0